# ORA-02315: incorrect number of arguments for default constructor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this table which I'm trying to get to work but I get an error whenever I try to insert into it, which I don't understand why I'm getting it. Any help would be greatly apreciated!

```
CREATE TYPE item AS OBJECT
(itemID NUMBER(6),
description CLOB) NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE TYPE producers_t AS OBJECT
(producerID NUMBER(3),
producer VARCHAR(35));
/
CREATE TYPE  producers_type AS TABLE OF REF producers_t;
/
CREATE TYPE dvds_typ UNDER item
(ISBN NUMBER(13),
subject VARCHAR(35),
title VARCHAR(150),
producers producers_type);
/
CREATE TABLE dvds_tab OF dvds_typ (PRIMARY KEY (itemID)
) NESTED TABLE producers STORE AS producers_ntab;
/
INSERT INTO dvds_tab
    VALUES (95, 'A dvd about...', '1324567891234', 'Sci-Fi', 'A long dvd',
        producers_t(producers_type(56, 'Gary')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You create the `producers_type` as `TABLE OF REF producers_t` but you are not passing in a `REF` value, you are passing in the base object. If you want to store non-`REF` values then create the type as:

```sql
CREATE TYPE  producers_type AS TABLE OF producers_t;
/
```

(And as [@AlexPoole pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65003525/1509264) swap `producers_t(producers_type(56, 'Gary'))` to `producers_type(producers_t(56, 'Gary'))` in your insert statement.)

For example:

```sql
CREATE TYPE item AS OBJECT(
  itemID      NUMBER(6),
  description CLOB
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE producers_t AS OBJECT(
  producerID NUMBER(3),
  producer   VARCHAR(35)
);

CREATE TYPE  producers_type AS TABLE OF producers_t;

CREATE TYPE dvds_typ UNDER item(
  ISBN      NUMBER(13),
  subject   VARCHAR(35),
  title     VARCHAR(150),
  producers producers_type
);

CREATE TABLE dvds_tab OF dvds_typ (
  PRIMARY KEY ( itemID )
) NESTED TABLE producers STORE AS producers_ntab;

INSERT INTO dvds_tab
VALUES (
  95,
  'A dvd about...',
  '1324567891234',
  'Sci-Fi',
  'A long dvd',
  producers_type(producers_t(56, 'Gary'))
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d1bdc5db334318549c2bacff2ada491)*

---

Since you are using object tables, another alternative would be to just create a table of `item`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items OF item (
  PRIMARY KEY ( itemID )
);

INSERT INTO items
VALUES (
  dvds_typ(
    95,
    'A dvd about...',
    '1324567891234',
    'Sci-Fi',
    'A long dvd',
    producers_type(producers_t(56, 'Gary'))
  )
);
```

Then, to get the data, you can use:

```sql
SELECT i.itemid,
       i.description,
       i.isbn,
       i.subject,
       i.title,
       p.producerid,
       p.producer
FROM   (
  SELECT i.itemId,
         i.description,
         TREAT(VALUE(i) AS dvds_typ).isbn      AS isbn,
         TREAT(VALUE(i) AS dvds_typ).subject   AS subject,
         TREAT(VALUE(i) AS dvds_typ).title     AS title,
         TREAT(VALUE(i) AS dvds_typ).producers AS producers
  FROM   items i
) i
OUTER APPLY TABLE( i.producers ) p
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ITEMID | DESCRIPTION    |          ISBN | SUBJECT | TITLE      | PRODUCERID | PRODUCER
> -----: | :------------- | ------------: | :------ | :--------- | ---------: | :-------
>     95 | A dvd about... | 1324567891234 | Sci-Fi  | A long dvd |         56 | Gary
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81f7f9d04dbb4aa3b1552831fac3bf7d)*

Comment: Thanks very much, I like the 2nd way, but unfortunatly I need to use the first way for uni!

Answer (score 1):

The initial error, caused by your confusing naming really, is that you have `producers_t` and `producers_type` the wrong way around:

```
INSERT INTO dvds_tab
    VALUES (95, 'A dvd about...', '1324567891234', 'Sci-Fi', 'A long dvd',
        producers_type(producers_t(56, 'Gary')));
```

But with your current definitions you need a collection of object references (as @MTO pointed out), so to use REFs you need to create those producer objects first in a separate table and then create a collection of the one(s) that are relevant to a specific DVD:

```
CREATE TABLE producers_tab OF producers_t (PRIMARY KEY(producerID));

INSERT INTO producers_tab
    VALUES (56, 'Gary');

INSERT INTO dvds_tab
    VALUES (95, 'A dvd about...', '1324567891234', 'Sci-Fi', 'A long dvd',
        (SELECT CAST(COLLECT(REF(p)) AS producers_type) 
            FROM producers_tab p WHERE producerID = 56));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c998418733c2d1009df1670603d89cd9)

To access the nested table data you need to dereference the REF with [the DEREF function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/DEREF.html#GUID-E551FFE4-619F-40CE-8303-683EFA3EB28F):

```
SELECT d.title,
  DEREF(p.column_value).producerID AS producerID,
  DEREF(p.column_value).producer AS producer 
FROM dvds_tab d
CROSS JOIN TABLE(d.producers) p;

TITLE      PRODUCERID PRODUCER
---------- ---------- --------
A long dvd         56 Gary
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=61be4dbe14028fce409794dd7e3cb5a3)

You can let Oracle do the dereference implicitly here:

```
SELECT d.title,
  p.column_value.producerID AS producerID,
  p.column_value.producer AS producer 
FROM dvds_tab d
CROSS JOIN TABLE(d.producers) p;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=878a8a8d51b355ae54a1de42e28fca39)

But it's a bit clearer with the explicit DEREF call. And depending on your Oracle version you could use `CROSS APPLY` instead of `CROSS JOIN`; or `OUTER` if you might not have any producers listed, perhaps.

The bit you were missing was the `column_value` step to get from the table expression to the actual object reference.

Comment: Its not quite what I said. I'd said to drop the `REF` from the type and just have a nested table of (unreferenced) objects. You've gone the other route and kept the `REF` and  created a separate table to reference from. Both are valid methods and it just depends on whether the OP wants to use object references or not.

Comment: Yes, misplaced the reference. I would assume you wouldn't want to duplicate the producers involved with multiple films. Particularly with an ID. But who knows. (But then I wouldn't use objects... have to love this kind of real-world-relevant exercise!)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. How would I go about showing the results and showing the publishers?
I've tried playing around with:
SELECT d.title, p.publisherID FROM dvds_tab d, TABLE(d.publisher) p
but it's not working.

Comment: @NeilWiddowson - you haven't shown a publisher in your question, but presumably you've added that in the same way you've implemented the producer(s); so I've added how to get that information back instead.